# Adding extra methods as type extensions in F#

Tags: f#, extension-methods

I have an .Net library that already has implemented `.Item` methods, e.g.

```
namespace Library2
type A() = 
    member m.Item with get(a: string) =   printfn "get a string"
    member m.Item with get(a: int) =   printfn "simple slice"
```

In the code that uses this library, I want to add one extra method of the same name (therefore it is `optional extensions`):

```
#r @"Library2.dll"
open Library2
type A with
    member m.Item with get(a: bool) =
        printfn "get a bool"
```

The last line of the following example does not compile:

```
let a = new A()
a.["good"]    
a.[10]
a.[true]
```

The [F# doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx) says:

> Extension methods cannot be virtual or abstract methods. They can
>   overload other methods of the same name, but the compiler gives
>   preference to non-extension methods in the case of an ambiguous call.

This means that I cannot extend `.ToString/.GetHashCode` with the same type signature, but here I use a different type signature. Why cannot the new method get extended?

Comment: What I find strange is that Intellisense shows all three overloads.

Comment: yes. this confuses me...

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is caused by the fact extension methods are implemented as the following (C#):

```cs
public static class MyModule
{
    public static void Item(this A a, bool b)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

The compiler is looking for `.Item(...)` method, finds it in the original `Library2.A` class, and fails to search for any extension methods.

Note that if *all* `.Item(...)` overloads are extension methods, everything works fine:

```
module Library2 =
    type A() = 
        member m.dummy = ()

open Library2
type A with
    member m.Item with get(a: string) =   printfn "get a string"
    member m.Item with get(a: int) =   printfn "simple slice"
    member m.Item with get(a: bool) = printfn "get a bool"
```

Comment: There is difference between intrinsic extension and optional extension. My case is `optional`.

Comment: Yes, intrinsic extensions are compiled into the type itself, just like `partial` classes in C#. [Optional extension members are compiled to static members for which the object instance is passed implicitly as the first parameter.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx), and this may be what causes the problem.

Comment: It's worth noting: F# supports extension properties, but C# does not. So there is no C# counterpart to what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the compiler. The extension method is there and can be called when you abstain from the nice syntactic sugar that comes with indexers, i.e. this works:

Library:

```
namespace TestLibrary

type A() = 
    member m.Item with get(a: string) = "string"
    member m.Item with get(a: int)    = "int"
```

Main:

```
open TestLibrary

type A with
    member m.Item with get(a: bool) = "bool"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let a = new A()
    printfn "%s" (a.get_Item "a")
    printfn "%s" (a.get_Item 1)
    printfn "%s" (a.get_Item true)
    System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

My first intuition was that an indexer cannot have `unit` as return type, but that didn't turn out to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I created a similar thing in LinqPad and it worked as you expected.

```
module ModuleA =

    type A() = 
        member m.Item with get(a: string) = printfn "get a string"
        member m.Item with get(a: int) = printfn "simple slice"

module ModuleB = 
    open ModuleA

    type A with
        member m.Item with get(a: bool) = printfn "get a bool"

open ModuleB

let a = new ModuleA.A()
a.["good"]    
a.[10]
a.[true]

// get a string
// simple slice
// get a bool
```